# Can you add validation to VSO/VSTS Work Item fields?

Tags: azure-devops

I was just trying to work out if it was possible to add validation to Work Item fields in Visual Studio Online / Team Services.

My use case is i want to make some fields mandatory if a certain condition is met (e.g. if Field1 = x then Field2 cannot be blank)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to do this. To achieve this feature, you need to [customize the process template and work item definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404857.aspx) which is not supported by VSTS for now.

There is already a feature request for this on VSTS User Voice: [Customize Process Template on Visual Studio Online](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3654231-customize-process-template-on-visual-studio-online) and MS keeps working on this. Refer to this link for details: [VSTS Process Customization futures (January 2016)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/01/11/vsts-process-customization-futures-january-2016/)